# Sheaf of rings on a discrete set.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, ringed-spaces

I was reading through some notes for an exam and one exericse asks me to prove the following

**There is a unique sheaf of rings making a topological set $X$ with discrete topology a ringed space.**

I tried doing it but I feel I'm missing something, using the definition of presheaf and than of sheaf doesn't seem to bring me any result.
How can I solve such a problem? I leave you my definitions of presheaf and sheaf.

> A presheaf $\mathfrak{F}$ (of rings) on a topological space X consists of the data:

> - for every open set $U\subset X$ a ring $\mathfrak{F}(U)$ (think of this as the ring of functions on U),
> - for every inclusion $U\subset V$ of open sets in X a ring homomorphism $\rho_{V,U}:\mathfrak{F}(V)\to \mathfrak{F}(U)$ called the restriction map (think of this as the usual restriction of functions to a subset),
>   such that
>
>   - $\mathfrak{F}(\varnothing)=0$
>   - $\rho_{U,U}$ is the identity map of $\mathfrak{F}(U)$ for all U,
>   - for any inclusion $U\subset V\subset W$ of open sets in X we have $\rho_{V,U}\circ \rho_{W,V}=\rho_{W,U}$

> The elements of $\mathfrak{F}(U)$ are usually called the sections of $\mathfrak{F}$ over U, and the restriction maps $\rho_{V,U}$
> are written as $\varphi\to \varphi|U$.

> A presheaf $\mathfrak{F}$ is called a sheaf of rings if it satisfies the following gluing property:
>
> - if U$\subset X$ is
>   an open set, $\{U_i : i \in I\}$ an arbitrary open cover of U and $\varphi_i\in \mathfrak{F}(U_i)$ sections for all i such that $\varphi_i|_{U_i\cap U_j}=\varphi_j|_{U_i\cap U_j}$
>   for all $i, j \in I$, then there is a unique $\varphi \in \mathfrak{F}(U)$ such that $\varphi|_{U_i} = \varphi_i$ for all i.

EDIT: added picture of the exercise text for reference in case I explained myself wrong

[image]

EDIT2: This is what is given as the definition of a K-ringed space:

> A ringed spaces equipped with a sheaf of rings such that the elements of $\mathfrak{O}_X(U)$ are actual functions from U to a fixed ring K;

EDIT3: It turns out that the actual definition is

> A ringed spaces equipped with a sheaf of rings such that the elements of $\mathfrak{O}_X(U)$ are actual functions from U to a fixed ring K and $\mathfrak{O}_X(U)$ is not only a subring of the ring of functions from $U\to K$ but a $sub-K-algebra$ of it;

What does this change?

Comment: I don't really see what you mean. I think instead of "granded" you mean "graded" but besides this: what does it mean for a topological space to be a graded ring?

Comment: I miswrote due to being tired, I of course meant "ringed space" (I edited it out)

Comment: I don't agree with the statement, what if we take a one point space $X$? Then there are as many ringed space structures as there are rings. Indeed, we can specify a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ by simply saying $\mathcal{F}(X)=A$ for any ring of our choice.

Comment: Indeed but still this is what I'm asked to prove, I added a picture of the exercise text, maybe I explained it wrong

Comment: @AlainNgalani, what is $K$? What do you mean by $K$-ringed space?

Comment: This does not make any sense. Of course there are a lot of way to make X a ringed space.in The picture it says K-ringed space and I guess it is the main point. Is K is algebraicly closed?is a K-ringed space is a sheaf of finitely generated K-algebras?please clarify this points

Comment: It doesn't specify, this is just in the middle of the exercise notes.
I suppose it can be that K is algebraically closed given that these are algebraic geometry notes, it also may be that we are talking about sheaves of functions with some properties given that I never used a general sheaf until now.
But these are just suppositions, I posted everything that was around the exercise.

I have no idea what a K-ringed space is, the main notes of the course never use this notation that only appear in the professor exercises

Comment: Where for sheaves of functions I mean what usually happens for a variety $X$ and $\mathfrak{O}_X(U)$ the sheaf of regular functions

Comment: I think your professor makes a mistake. maybe he wanted to say a variety over $K$ instead of K-ringed space. I can't imagine any possible definition of a K ringed space that can make your exercise true.

Comment: @ali I added the definition of K-ringed space, I feel like the counterexamples still work but maybe you can help me say this is not the case

Comment: The problem statement _still_ doesn't make sense. Your definition of $K-$ringed space defines a unique sheaf of functions on _any_ space at all –– not just a discrete space. Indeed, $U\mapsto \{f:U\to K\}$ defines a sheaf of rings on any space at all, and the sheaf is uniquely characterized by this property.

Comment: @AlekosRobotis You should read the definition a bit more loosely: I think the author means $O_X (U)$ is a _subring_ of the ring of all functions $U \to K$. But then this is still underspecified because it does not force uniqueness for a point. Perhaps the author should have written that all rings are $K$-algebras.

Comment: Perhaps what is meant is locally constant sheaf valued in $K$? Then this becomes a rather standard problem.

Comment: I read it exactly as "a ring whose element are all functions from U to K (not necessarly every function from U to K)".
Morover the one I posted is exactly the response I got after asking fro calrification so I don't think he mean locally constant.
Anyway in case he asks me I'll bring him the counterexample of the set with only one element, thanks for the help. at least now I know it was not just me thet found the problem strange

Comment: @ZhenLin It turns out we are actually talking about a K-algebra, does this make the exercise easy?

Comment: I wrote more details in the third EDIT

Comment: I don't know about easy but at least you have a true statement now. Show that the only possibility for a point is $K$ itself, and then use the sheaf property for a disjoint union of points.

Comment: @ZhenLin Can you expand on this? What do you mean by K itself? K is not an algebra of functions from U to K

Comment: It is isomorphic to the ring of $K$-valued functions on a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a $K$-ringed space has a very specific meaning, namely that the associated sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is a $K$-subalgebra of the $K$-algebra $\operatorname{Mor}(U, K)$. In particular this means that $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ contains the constant functions.

A set $X$ with the discrete topology has the trivial open covering $$X = \bigcup_{x \in X} x, $$ where we identify $x$ with the set $\{x\}$. The sheaf axioms then give that we can decompose any sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ over an open subset $U$ as $$\mathcal{F}(U) \cong \prod_{x \in U} \mathcal{F}(x).$$ After all the intersection of $x \cap y$ for any distinct elements is empty. For $\mathcal{F}(x)$ to sheaf for a $K$-ringed space we need it to be a $K$-subalgebra of $K_x := \operatorname{Mor}(x, K)$ and must contain the constant functions. But all elements of $\operatorname{Mor}(x, K)$ are constant functions and the set can be identified with $K$. We must thus have $\mathcal{F}(x) = K_x$ for all $x \in X$. It follows that for a $K$-ringed space with the specified conditions we must have $$\mathcal{O}_X(U) \cong \prod_{u \in U} K.$$ It is easy to see existence of a presheaf defined that way and the sheaf axioms  hold because the restriction maps come from dropping terms in the product.

Answer (score 1):

This is just summing up the comment discussion:
it seems that the question is badly posed, as a counterexample of what seems the most senseful interpretation of it we can take the space $X=\{x\}$ to which we can associate any ring to form a ringed space, and even restricting to rings of functions from $\{x\}\to K$ for K a field we don't have uniqueness